# Dependencies of Electrum bitcoin wallet in different distros

Tags: arch-linux, fedora, dependencies, void-linux, bitcoin

What are the Dependencies of Electrum bitcoin wallet in different distros?

1. void
2. opensuse-tumbleweed
3. opensuse-leap
4. nethunter
5. fedora
6. centos
7. backbox
8. arch
9. alpine

I know it's the same in these three distros:

ubuntu
kali
debian

```
$ sudo  apt-get install  python3-pip  python3-pyqt5 libsecp256k1-0 python3-cryptography python3-setuptools libcairo2-dev 
pkg-config python3-dev -y && sudo python3 -m pip install pycairo
```

Comment: [The readme appears pretty clear?](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum#getting-started) Why would other distros need something else?

Comment: @Panki
Package managers are different. This only works for apt. how about dnf (fedora), pacman (arch), apk (alpine)...etc. Package names are also sometimes different.

Comment: Wouldn't the package manager pull in those dependencies? I'm wondering what the motivation for the question is.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Not all of them. And you do not know which one

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 34:

```
(python3.9dist(aiohttp) < 4 with python3.9dist(aiohttp) >= 3.3)
(python3.9dist(aiorpcx) < 0.19 with python3.9dist(aiorpcx) >= 0.18)
/usr/bin/python3
libsecp256k1
python(abi) = 3.9
python3-cryptography
python3.9dist(aiohttp-socks) >= 0.3
python3.9dist(attrs) >= 19.2
python3.9dist(bitstring)
python3.9dist(certifi)
python3.9dist(dnspython) >= 2
python3.9dist(protobuf) >= 3.12
python3.9dist(pyqt5)
python3.9dist(qdarkstyle) < 2.9
python3.9dist(qrcode)
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how to install these packages with one click? I think PyCairo will be needed too. ```sudo dnf install cairo-devel pkg-config python3-devel
```

Comment: `dnf install electrum` will pull all the dependencies ;-)

Comment: I want to install it manually, not by default

Comment: `dnf install --downloadonly electrum` - the downloaded rpms will be in `/var/cache/dnf`

Comment: It works, but you need at least two and a half gigabytes of space to install it. Which is three times apt. although after installation, part of the space can be emptied. But definitely not before it.